# how to find two different strings in the same line in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, find

I have a cell obtained from text scan and I want to find the index of lines containing particular string,

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
E = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
```

and I wanted to know the line numbers (index) of those lines which have a specific text, e.g. I wanted to find the rows that have the keyword "2016":

```
rows = find(contains(E{1},"2016" );
```

but I want to find the index of those lines which have two keywords "2016" and "Mathew Perry" (only those lines which have both the keywords).

I tried using this code but does not work

```
rows = find(contains(E{1},"2016" && contains(E{1},"Mathew Perry");
```

the error I get is:

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Comment: replace `||` with `|` and `&&` with `&`

Comment: You have some errors in your code which I'm assuming are just question typos and not in your actual code - missing closing brackets for all of your `contains` functions! For more information about what EBH has said and the difference between `&` and `&&`, see the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html#bu46s7m-4)

Answer (score 0):

To find a single string:

```
idx = strfind(E{1}, '2016');
idx = find(not(cellfun('isempty', idx)));
```

Use *strfind* instead of find. YOu may try the above with and/or. If it works fine, then no problem; if not, get the indices separately for each word and get the intersection of the indices.

Comment: The OP's problem is with the `&&` error, don't think you've really addressed that.

Comment: If it doesn't work, indices of individual string can be used via intersection of sets.

Comment: contains is new to 16b and should be preferred in this situation. contains is much faster than strfind for large string arrays.